# Sci fi card game adapted to anime with neon green cat girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching the anime and the story was okay i guess but i couldn't get the opening song out of my head. I remember the opening had the word freedom in it. The anime started with this girl who is a hacker she wore neon green and black with cat ear headphones. Then the perspective changed to a highschool guy with his ai girl robot which he uses to fight with other ai's. The girl ai i remember had blue eyes and grey hair(i think). When i searched the anime back then i remember seeing it was a card game adaption to anime.

Comment: Welcome Justa..... What language was it in, what year?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had this opening stuck in my head for like a year. The freedom part i think i messed it up with private wars from a rise lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Zenonzard: The Animation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11884906/)*** (2019–2020)...?

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/Zenonzard):

> ***Zenonzard: The Animation* is an anime series produced by Studio 8-bit. It is part of the overall *Zenonzard* media franchise and adapts the *Zenonzard* card game by Bandai Namco Entertainment.** Episode 0 of the series premiered in September 10, 2019, on *Zenonzard's* official YouTube channel, with television channels broadcasting Episode 0 in September 13 of that same year. The full series premiered on January 2020, with episodes getting released on a monthly basis.

> Many years into the future, the Zenonzard card game has become the most popular hobby all over the world. Zenonzard players, aided by sophisticated AI units called "Codemen", tirelessly compete against each other to earn the right to enter the Zenon, a special dimension that hosts battles between the best players in the world. Sota Azuma dreamed of entering the Zenon and becoming a champion, but that dream faded after enduring a friendless childhood. Fortunately, the arrival of a special Codeman called Eilietta Lash gives Sota the chance to fulfill his dream once again.

At the start of the episode 1, we're introduced to a female hacker named [Hinaria Darkend](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/hinaria-darkend), who wears black and green, and has cat ears on her hood. We're later introduced to the protagonist -- high school student, [Souta Azuma](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/sota-azuma) -- and his gynoid AI, [Eilietta Lash](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/eilietta-lash), who has blue eyes and mostly black or dark blue hair.